# How do I show UpComing Facebook Friends Birthdays in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am writing an app in which i am getting List of Friends in form of January to December as you can see in screen shot

Now i want to show in form of Upcoming Facebook Friends Birthdays by using current date...please someone help me...

Like in below image you can see i am getting friends on top, those birthdays has gone away, but still i am getting on top, so i just want to show list in form of Upcoming birthdays

```
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try 
        {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

        FriendItem friendItem;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listfb_friends, null);
            friendItem = new FriendItem();
            convertView.setTag(friendItem);
        } else 
        {
            friendItem = (FriendItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        friendItem.friendPicture = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.picture);
        friendItem.friendName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.name);
        friendItem.friendDob = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.dob);
        friendItem.friendLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.friend_item);

        try 
        {
            String uid = jsonObject.getString("uid");
            String url = jsonObject.getString("pic_square");
            friendItem.friendPicture.setImageBitmap(picturesGatherer.getPicture(uid, url));
        } catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            friendItem.friendName.setText("");
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("Birthday Not Mentioned");
        }

        try 
        {
            friendItem.friendName.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            friendItem.friendDob.setText(jsonObject.getString("birthday"));

            if(!(jsonObject.getString("birthday").equalsIgnoreCase("null")))
            {
            friendItem.friendDob.setText(jsonObject.getString("birthday"));
            }
            else
            {
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("Birthday Not Added");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            friendItem.friendName.setText("");
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("");
        }
        listofshit.put(position, friendItem);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Query to Fetch Records:

```
    String query = "SELECT name, birthday, uid, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())AND birthday_date >= '01/01' AND birthday_date <= '31/12' ORDER BY birthday_date";
```

original code you can find here:

```
https://github.com/chrtatu/FacebookFriendsList
```

Comment: So whats your issue???

Comment: @altaf buddy fetching list of friends with their DOB now i just want to show Notification on Birthdays..

Comment: I think you should start service fo know upcoming birtday then send notification

Comment: @Harpreet hi.. buddy now i just want to show upcoming birthdays not notification, if possible so please help..

Comment: Store the data from FB to list, use a for loop to check the d.o.b greater than today. Add just those entries from JSON to new a list which will be used to view. And now View that list in Upcoming b'day column (or whatever you are using at your end)

Comment: @Harpreet i have tried several times could you please show me how code looks like?